# Direction of a bearing

Tags: geometry

What is the direction in degrees that corresponds to the bearing S 48 W?  Do not give any units in your answer.  As usual, your answer should consist only of a number.  Your answer must be between -180 and 179.

so since its -(90+48)= -138  correct?

This is the theory i have in my textbook
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem, but I really don't understand why there's a 480 in the problem and a 48 in your solution. Or is that 480 supposed to be 48 degrees?

Comment: @GerryMyerson oops typo.. sorry was trying to put the degree there

Comment: If S $48$ W means $48$° west of due south, a bearing of $0$ is due north, bearings clockwise from that are positive, and bearings counterclockwise from that are negative, then $-138$ is not correct: it should be $-180+48=-132$. However, I don’t know whether my assumptions are correct.

Comment: I would concur with Brian's answer. More typically it would be expressed as 228°.

Comment: @copper.hat take a look at my textbook explanation..

Comment: What you have in your textbook confirms my guess at the meaning of $S $48$° W but doesn’t have any bearing (sorry!) on the other assumptions.

Comment: Agree with copper.hat. I have never seen a compass dial with negative numbers. Quite irrespective of what OP's textbook says. OTOH adding/subtracting a multiple of 360 to accomodate for the whims of a textbook author is also a basic skill. Anyway I'm fairly sure that copper.hat was simply making the observation that the prescribed interval of length 360 is an odd choice in the context of compass bearings.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ya i also knew that there is no negative compass.. u know wat i am going to clarify this with my teacher and going to show him this post haha..

Comment: What did the teacher say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was in high school we used this notation for bearings.  The notation S 48 W is interpreted as beginning at south, then rotating 48 degrees towards the West direction.  The angle in degrees, which in this context should be measured from the North direction, is thus -180 + 48 = -132 degrees.

Note: It is negative because the direction is typically measured from the North direction and clockwise.  Our bearing is 132 degrees counter-clockwise from North and therefore negative.

Comment: i will clarify with my lecturer and update this later tonight!! perhaps who knows both answers are correct...

Comment: so looks like i am right i clarified with my teacher he said both the answers can be right but depends on the question..